# Condition on $a$ for matrix to be positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Assume you are given an $n\times n$ matrix with all elements equal to $a$, except for the diagonal values which are all $1$. What would be the condition on $a$ so that the matrix be positive definite?

Comment: Took a while to understand... next time, please use LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

This matrix is $(1-a) I + aJ$ where $J$ is the matrix of all ones.
What are the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Hints:

> $J$ is a rank one matrix whose only nonzero eigenvalue is $n$.

${}$

> The eigenvalues of $(1-a)I + aJ$ are $(1-a) + an$ and $1-a$. You want both of these to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there is an equivalent condition for a matrix to be positive definite. 
Namely, all upper left minors need to have a positive determinant. Check where this takes you.